ng2-pdf-viewer with Angular 18
I've tried to display a PDF in my angular 18 app, but I get a weird behavior. I've used https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer and called the module in my standalone component.
My ts file
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet,PdfViewerModule ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'viewer';
}


My html
<pdf-viewer
      [src]="'https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf'"
      [rotation]="0"
      [original-size]="false"
      [show-all]="true"
      [fit-to-page]="false"
      [zoom]="1"
      [zoom-scale]="'page-width'"
      [stick-to-page]="false"
      [render-text]="true"
      [external-link-target]="'blank'"
      [autoresize]="true"
      [show-borders]="false"
      style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"
    ></pdf-viewer> 

The error
document is not defined
at eval (C:\Users\anass.sbai\Desktop\viewe\viewer\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\web\pdf_viewer.mjs:431:18)
at async instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/anass.sbai/Desktop/viewe/viewer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chun

Based on error it looks like there is use browser-specific APIs like document in a server-side rendering (SSR) environment. Can you can try to use a library like Domino to create a virtual DOM environment.

You are having server side rendering enabled in your application, this project uses window object which only exists in browser, when you render on the server, window will be undefined.
Wrap the PDF, inside a defer block inside its own component, this component will render only when on the browser, so when you use this component, make sure you wrap the component inside the defer block.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pdf-viewer',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet,PdfViewerModule ],
  template: `
    <pdf-viewer
      [src]="'https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf'"
      [rotation]="0"
      [original-size]="false"
      [show-all]="true"
      [fit-to-page]="false"
      [zoom]="1"
      [zoom-scale]="'page-width'"
      [stick-to-page]="false"
      [render-text]="true"
      [external-link-target]="'blank'"
      [autoresize]="true"
      [show-borders]="false"
      style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"
    ></pdf-viewer> 
  `,
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class PdfViewerComponent {
  title = 'viewer';
}

Then when you use this component, make sure you wrap it inside the defer block.
@defer() {
    <app-pdf-viewer/>
}

